# ${\rm Cov}(X,Y)=1/4 \times ({\rm Var}(XY)-{\rm Var}(X/Y))$

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

I saw that formula in this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2103304), equation (1.3).

The formula should hold for all the random variables such that those functionals are properly defined. I have been trying to prove it, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that that identity is not true in general. Consider for instance $ X = Y$. Then we'd have

$$
\text{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{4} \text{Var}(X^2)
$$

but if, e.g. $\mathbb{P}(X=1) = \mathbb{P}(X=2) = 1/2$, that is false.

Comment: I agree, it looked too good to be true tbh. Thanks a lot